# Visual Studio Code cannot properly reference packages in the virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I am using VSCODE for my Python development on Windows 10.

As shown in the screenshot below, I use a virtual environment, and my virtual environment includes required libraries.

However, VSCODE shows the following problems:

- "**pyplot**": Unknown word.
- "**numpy**": Unknown word.

**The program runs fine**. I just need to fix the two problems pointed in the screenshot below:

[image]

It seems that some parts of VSCODE are not considering my virtual environment and try to find the unknown words in the Python installation outside the virtual environment.

How can I properly eliminate the above two "Unknown word" problems?

Comment: This is because VS Code wasn't built for python, but I think you can disable some types of warnings like typos

Comment: The problem is likely that a different Python environment is being used for syntax highlighting and hinting than what is being used when you run your program.  If you have more than one Python installation, or are using virtual environments, then this is very possible.  I'd suggest that you try to find where the Python plugin for VSC determines which Python interpreter to use when hinting in the editor.

Comment: @Yash, I think you are severely underestimating VSCODE. It recives massive money investment and it changes quite fast. If you know it back in 2019, you need to check it again every year.

Comment: @CryptoFool, What you are explaining makes sense. I just need to find a supported way to fix the configuration of that syntax higligter.

Comment: it depends if the virtual environment is a child directory of the workspace, if so it should work out of the box and VSC should activate the Virt-Env when you open the workspace, otherwise have a look at the setting `python.analysis.extraPaths`

Comment: Have you tried if cSpell supports imports without virtual environments? See, for example [this](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker/issues/203). If it does not work without a virtual environment, could you consider using other tools, like pylint?

Comment: @Allan Xu -I tested it with the same code in virtual environment and global environment and it did not display the "Unknown word" message. It seems that this is provided by "cSpell", and the python code analysis tool Pylint does not display any warnings.

Comment: @JillCheng and  np8, does this mean cSpell does not support virtual environments?

Comment: @Allan Xu  -When you use the global python environment, is the "Unknown word" information displayed here as well? If it also displays this information, this is not a problem of using the python environment, but a problem of cSpell analyzing python code.

Comment: @JillCheng, Thank you for help. Is there any way to have cSpell better integrate with Python so that it won't raise issues on Python's valid library symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an editor, VS Code itself does not display "Unknown word" information. According to the screenshot information you provided, the "Unknown word" information is provided by cSpell.

In VS Code, we use the [Linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) function provided by the python extension (it contains Pylint, flake8, mypy, etc.) to analyze the python code, and it will display the problems in the code on the VS Code terminal. (Of course, some python language services will also display problems from the code.)

It is recommended that you use the python code analysis tool Pylint when analyzing python code in VS Code. In the code in this thread, it will not display the "Unknown word" message:

[image]

Reference: [The use of Pylint in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_enable-linters).

Comment: Is there any way to instruct cSpell not to raise a problem when the symbok coming from Python packages?

Comment: @Allan Xu -"cSpell" is not Linting in VS Code,  it is usually not used by default, so you could find its settings in the settings file "settings.json" and set it to "false" or comment it out (_"cSpell.enabled": false,_) or you could "disable" the 'cSpell' extension in VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

These words actually do not exist in python's dictionary.
Add python new words to the python dictionary (click the yellow light bulb with the mouse to see the upper button (the mouse touch the blue circle exclamation mark to see the yellow light bulb))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Jku.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was the result of the Python *Linter* checks. I disabled it by editing/creating a file `.vscode/settings.json` (project's root directory) and adding:

```json
{
    "cSpell.enabled": false
}
```